# CSS transition to work when object is toggled by jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this simple horizontal chart script.
When you click on the button, width of the filler changes to 100%.

I've tried to add transition to the `.filler`, but it does not work.

How can I animate it?

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  $(".filler").css("width", "100%");
  $(".filler").html("100%");
});
```

```css
.borders {
margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.filler {
background-color: green;
white-space: nowrap;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me to fill the chart</button>

<div class="borders">
<div class="filler" style="width:15%;">15%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add transition to filter class

```
.filter {transition: all 0.5s;}
```